# Can we color Code or have colored display for puts in tcl?

Tags: tcl, itcl

i have some output in tcl which is printed using puts like this:

```
puts "hello world"
```

can we print the same in different color?

Comment: What OS do you want to do this in?

Comment: @slebetman : on FreeBSD machine and linux machine

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

For example, to print line in bold red color:

```
puts -nonewline "\033\[1;31m"; #RED
puts "My RED String"
puts -nonewline "\033\[0m";# Reset
```

[image]

Comment: I find that it is easiest to store the escape sequences in variables and just use that. A global array is pretty neat for this thing: lets you do `puts "$ANSI(fg,red)My RED String$ANSI(reset)"` and that's a lot clearer than putting the escape sequence itself all over the place.

Comment: I'm totally agree!

Comment: The tcllib `term` package and its subpackages might be useful for this. It contains commands for many ansi sequences.

Comment: Ah this is helpful.. Thanku guys

Comment: Hey guys , can we have the same color coded message  for 'error' command in tcl? something like this?
     if {1+2 != 3} {
        error "something is very wrong with addition"
     }

Can the error message be printed in red color?

Comment: i just tried this and it worked:

if {1+2 != 4} {
>error "\033\[1;31m my error \033\[0m "
>}
 my error
while evaluating {if {1+2 != 4} {
error "\033\[1;31m my error \033\[0m "
}}


The 'my error' was in red color, any other ways to enhance this command?